# Manipulating some data inside an each loop

Tags: javascript, meteor

What I want to achieve is very simple. In my collection I store the `name` of a certain object like this: `name: John`.

But when I link to it I want the name to say `john`, not `John`.

My template:

```
{{#each people}}
  <a href="/{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Helper:

```
people: function() {
  return People.find()
}
```

What I'd like to do is register a helper like this:

```
Template.registerHelper('toLowerCase', function(name) {
  return name.toLowerCase()
})
```

And then work it in somehow:

```
<a href="/{{toLowerCase '{{name}}'}}">{{name}}</a>
```

This, however, doesn't work. So what's the best solution?

Comment: Because this is a purely display issue, I'd use a css `text-transform: lowercase` instead.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Not really sure how I would pinpoint the url with that and not the text displayed between the anchor tags.

Comment: Oops sorry I misread the question. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name would be available as a variable within the handlebar tags.

The following should work.

```
<a href="/{{toLowerCase name }}">{{name}}</a>
```

Comment: If you are using iron-router, you should explore using 'pathFor' and passing the name as a parameter instead of creating links line in your sample code.

Comment: Ah, that was easy. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Call the helper this way

```
<a href="/{{toLowerCase name}}">{{name}}</a>
```

You shouldn't wrap arguments in {{ and }}